# PHP: make a function

Tags: php

```
function fullname($id){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$full_name = $row["firstname"] . " ".$row["lastname"];

return $full_name;
}
```

I want to grab firstname and lastname, put them together, and then echo it back, is this right?

Comment: Have you tried? Does it work? If yes, it is probably right. Just a note: If the `id` is an integer, you should not enclose it in single quotes: `"SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id = $id"`.

Comment: It should work if your $query work. But if you ask is it works, it's it doesn't work, nop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if id field is an integer you do not have to use like 'id'

this is the correct line of code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id = $id");
```

Comment: Better make sure $id is in fact a number first. `if(!is_numeric($id)) {return false;}` Though if `id` is unsigned, `is_int($id)` might be better.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you join firstname and lastname in the sql?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT concat(firstname, ' ',lastname) as 'Name' FROM users WHERE id = $id");
```

normally this should also work

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT firstname + ' ' + lastname as 'Name' FROM users WHERE id = $id");
```